# How to choose “safeboot" and minimal from System Config msconfig when only using keyboard

Tags: windows-10, keyboard-shortcuts, safe-mode, black-screen-of-death, msconfig

Im on windows 10 and i messed up in my resolution refresh rate, now my monitor has no display after doing some ways to go to safe mode to fix it but never boot in safe mode i guess the system configuration is the only way to go my pc in safe mode with only keyboard using because i dont have installation disk or flash drive and mouse pointer to display,can someone know how to navigat through this as black screen

Answer (score 0):

To boot blindly into Safe mode:

- <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>
- `msconfig` <kbd>Enter</kbd>
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd>
- <kbd>Tab</kbd>
- <kbd>Tab</kbd>
- <kbd>Space</kbd>
- <kbd>Enter</kbd>
- <kbd>Tab</kbd>
- <kbd>Enter</kbd>

and wait for the reboot (if everything was done correctly).

Alternatively, restarting the computer by the Power button 3 times might also work.